# questions/{id} API method: pagesize parameter?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm trying to get the lightest data about a given question id because i just need the question's title.

With this call:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/1598715?pagesize=1

i get `"pagesize": 100` on result.

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 100,
  ....
```

**EDIT:**
Fixed!

Comment: Same here, even though it only returns one.

Comment: The result collection has only one element total and fits on one page, so the pagesize is really irrelevant at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use questions/{id}/answers method to fetch more than first page of answers